# How can I remove everything in a line except my matching regex?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am using Notepad++ and using find and replace to remove everything in a line except the matches found by my string.

For example:

Line 1.  This is sample. 775 657 7576 sample line 1

Line 2. Second sample line.  661-525-5366 sample line 2

Line 3. Third line sample 466.755.7888. Line 3

Using regex `\d{3}\D?\d{3}\D?\d{4}` to match above numbers and remove everything else in its respecting line, resulting in it looking like this

Line 1.  775 657 7576

Line 2.  661-525-5366

Line 3.  466.755.7888

Answer (score 0):

This is very easy, actually. Just use this regular expression:

```
(?>\d{3}\D?\d{3}\D?\d{4}\K|[\s\S])
```

How it works:

This regular expression tries to match a phone number with your regular expression indicated. If it does then it will remove it from the match with `\K`. If it doesn't then it just captures 1 character with `[\s\S]` (better version of `.` as it captures newlines as well).

Use this regular expression to find everything else and replace it with empty space.

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/aM9vZ1/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
 ^.*?\b(\d{3}\D?\d{3}\D?\d{4})\b.*$
```

You can use this and replace by `$1` or `\1`.[See demo.](https://regex101.com/r/jK6eD8/3)

Comment: Thanks. After I do that. I use [^0-9\n] and replace with nothing so that I get a single 10 digit number, like 5554445555, some other lines give me numbers that are more than 10 characters or less than 10 characters long. how can i remove anything that isnt exactly 10 numbers?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using grouping concept in regex find and replace.
Split your line into 3 parts and replace it with the portion you wish.

**Find What :**`(^.*)(\d{3}\D?\d{3}\D?\d{4})(.*)`

- Part Before your pattern   **`(^.*)`**
- Your match pattern  **`(\d{3}\D?\d{3}\D?\d{4})`**
- After your Match Pattern **`(.*)`**

**Replace With :**`\2`

- Replace it with 2nd group

Snapshot of how this can be done
[image]